# Mono for Android Widget tutorials

Tags: c#, android

Are there any tutorials for creating a simple homescreen widget using Mono for Android (C#)? On the official site there is only code for a widget, no tutorial. All I would like to do is write some text to the widget and update the text every x.

Answer (score 0):

When you set updatePeriodMillis attribute value it's not guaranteed for your onUpdate method to be called with that period exactly, you have to deal with AlarmManager.

From https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/SimpleWidget, replace onUpdate like this:

```
private PendingIntent service = null;  

    public override void OnUpdate (Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        //// To prevent any ANR timeouts, we perform the update in a service
        //context.StartService (new Intent (context, typeof (UpdateService)));

        AlarmManager m = (AlarmManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

       Intent i = new Intent (context, typeof (UpdateService));

       if (service == null)
       {
           service = PendingIntent.GetService(context, 0, i, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
       }

       m.SetRepeating(AlarmType.Rtc, 0, 1000 * 3, service);
    }
```

Then in the service:

```
WordEntry entry = new WordEntry() { Title = "test", Description = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() };
```

The widget will refresh time every 3 seconds.

Hope this helps.